# Syntax in align environment

Tags: align, amsmath

Take a look at this here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Leftrightarrow \qquad P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} && (2.6)\\
\Leftrightarrow \qquad e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to have the equivalences below each other like the equations are?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
P'_1(t)&=-\lambda P_1(t)+\lambda P_0(t)\\
\Leftrightarrow &&\qquad  P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} && (2.6)\\
\Leftrightarrow &&  e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

This almost works but i have the mention problem that the first line is pulled to the very left.

Comment: Of course, you *don't* want to add the equation number manually, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\Leftrightarrow&& P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \tag{2.6} \\
\Leftrightarrow&& e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost -  if i have another line above the first \Leftrightarrow - Line it pulls the term to the very left "&&"-sign :/

Answer (score 3):

You *don't* want to manually number your equations and not because of the fact that the numbers would be unaligned to each other, but because maintaining manual numbering is essentially impossible.

Use the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism for this.

Your problem can be solved with `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

% let's emulate being in section 2 with five
% numbered equations before this one; a real document
% will have nothing like this
\setcounter{section}{2}\setcounter{equation}{5} 

\begin{equation}\label{equivalenteqs}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  \Leftrightarrow &\qquad& P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \\
  \Leftrightarrow &\qquad& e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)
                           &=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
As we see in equation~\eqref{equivalenteqs} we can blah blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you happen to have a first line without the arrows, just add the suitable number of alignment points:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

% let's emulate being in section 2 with five
% numbered equations before this one
\setcounter{section}{2}\setcounter{equation}{5} 

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
                &\qquad&  P'_1(t)&=-\lambda P_1(t)+\lambda P_0(t)\\
\Leftrightarrow &      &  P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \\
\Leftrightarrow &      &  e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \\
\Leftrightarrow &      & \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\lambda t}P_1(t))&=e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)=\lambda\\
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
As we see in equation~\eqref{equivalenteqs} we can blah blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I see no reason for aligning at the equals signs.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

% let's emulate being in section 2 with five
% numbered equations before this one
\setcounter{section}{2}\setcounter{equation}{5} 

\begin{equation}\label{equivalenteqs}
\begin{aligned}
                && & P'_1(t)=-\lambda P_1(t)+\lambda P_0(t)\\
\Leftrightarrow && & P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \\
\Leftrightarrow && & e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \\
\Leftrightarrow && & \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\lambda t}P_1(t))=e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)=\lambda\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
As we see in equation~\eqref{equivalenteqs} we can blah blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You also might be interested in the `ArrowBetweenLines` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2}\setcounter{equation}{5}

\begin{equation}\label{equivalenteqs}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
 & & abc & =def \\
 \ArrowBetweenLines &\qquad& P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines &\qquad& e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)
                           &=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
As we see in equation~\eqref{equivalenteqs} we can blah blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `alignat`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  \Leftrightarrow &&\qquad P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t) &=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} && (2.6) \\
  \Leftrightarrow &&\qquad e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t) &=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Same problem here:  if i have another line above the first \Leftrightarrow - Line it pulls the term to the very left "&&"-sign :/

Comment: Each `&` provide right alignment for the text before and left alignment for the left after, but without knowing more details it is difficult to help you further. Please update your test case in the question to more accurately reflect the issue you are having.