# Syntax (equations) in align environment

Tags: align

i have a problem with syntax in the align environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
P'_1(t)&=-\lambda P_1(t)+\lambda P_0(t)\\
\Leftrightarrow &&\qquad  P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} && (2.6)\\
\Leftrightarrow &&  e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \\
\Leftrightarrow && \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\lambda t}P_1(t))&=e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)=\lambda\\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

I just want to have the first line exactly above the equation in the second line but the && commands are pulling the first line to the left. Is there any easy possibility to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: In what, precisely, does this question differ from your previous one? You're just missing to add alignment points in the first line; you need to start it with `&&`. And you have already been told that adding equation numbers by hand is very bad.

Comment: Previous question for reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464802/107497

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{equation}{5}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
 & & P'_1(t)&=-\lambda P_1(t)+\lambda P_0(t) \notag\\
\Leftrightarrow && P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \\
\Leftrightarrow &\qquad& e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)&=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \notag\\
\Leftrightarrow && \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\lambda t}P_1(t))&=e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)=\lambda \notag
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is quite similar to [@Bernard's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464971/5001). The main difference is in the use of an `alignedat` environment that's nested inside an ordinary `equation` environment. With this approach, no `\notag` statements are needed, and the equation number will be automatically centered vertically on the system of four equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{5}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&&P'_1(t)
  &=-\lambda P_1(t)+\lambda P_0(t)\\
\Leftrightarrow
&&P'_1(t)+\lambda P_1(t)
  &=\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \\
\Leftrightarrow
&&\quad e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)
  &=\lambda e^{\lambda t} e^{-\lambda t}=\lambda \\
\Leftrightarrow
&&\frac{d}{dt}[e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)]
  &=e^{\lambda t}P'_1(t)+\lambda e^{\lambda t}P_1(t)=\lambda
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```